# Spell number in excel 2013 using 2 rows

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I'm trying to contain 2 rows whenever I use spell number in excel 2013,
I wanted to get the second output. Any idea?

[image]

*Note: SpellNumber is a Microsoft provided User Defined Function
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213360/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-english-words-in-excel*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Splitting the Number**

Top Row: `=SpellNumber((TRUNC(J7/100)*100))`

Second Row: `=SpellNumber(J7 - (TRUNC(J7/100)*100))`

(where `J7` is the cell of your numerical value.)

That will split the number apart, but spell number will still spell out to the cent for the first row like this...

> Ten Thousand One Hundred Pesos No Centavos

---

**Splitting the Text**

To only get the text before the "Pesos No Centavos" or "Dollars and No Cents" portion use something like this...

`=LEFT(SpellNumber((TRUNC(J7/100)*100)),FIND("Pesos",SpellNumber(TRUNC(J7/100)*100))-2)`

Or this might be more currency agnostic...

`=LEFT(SpellNumber((TRUNC(J7/100)*100)),FIND("Hundred",SpellNumber(TRUNC(J7/100)*100))+6)`

If you're splitting on the text "Hundred", then you could get by with the top equation just being this...

`=LEFT(SpellNumber(J7),FIND("Hundred",SpellNumber(J7))+6)`

For more information about splitting text in Excel, see here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68

---

*Note: SpellNumber is a Microsoft provided User Defined Function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213360/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-english-words-in-excel*

Comment: im totally a newbie here, how can i execute trunc?

Comment: @DrewCordaño With your entire equation like this... `=SpellNumber((TRUNC(I17/100)*100))`

Comment: so it would be =spellnumber(j7(TRUNK(j71/100)*100)?

Comment: @DrewCordaño Close, you have a `J7` multiplying your `Trunc` function that shouldn't be there... I updated my answer with `J7` as the range... the simple euqation would be something like this `=spellnumber((TRUNK(j71/100)*100)`

Comment: the code to get bfore dollars and cent isn't working

Comment: @DrewCordaño Aww, that's cause you're using "Pesos" amigo ;)

Comment: I'm getting "Pesos" at top and bottorm row, which isn't appropriate.

Comment: @DrewCordaño Right, the code I posted before split the string whereever there was the text `Dollars`, but you're using Pesos, so you need to search for "Pesos" and not "Dollars" in the string... or use the equation I posted that's currency agnostic and searches for "Hundred" and splits the string based on that instead.